# Understand how a buffered channel works

Tags: go

Can someone explain to me how channels work in these scenerios:

1. If a channel isn't buffered, if you send to a channel 2 messages when no message has been received yet, does it just block the app?
2. If there is a buffer, it behaves like #1 once the bufferred amount is reached?  So if the buffer is 2, after 2 messages it will just block until you recieve at least 1 message?

Since you have to set the bufferred amount, you can't just have a channel that stores an arbitrary amount of messages?

Comment: You seem to have just supplied your own answers phrased as questions. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @JimB I know how scala actors work, and actors seem to be a unbounded queue and was curious how to get the same behavior with go channels.

Comment: no, you cannot have an unbounded channel, but you already answered that, then put a question mark at the end. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. No, you can't have an infinite-buffered channel.

This is covered in detail [in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Basically, whenever a routine sends on a channel, that routine blocks until *something* is available to receive it. That may be the channel buffer, or it may be something trying to receive from the channel. Likewise, whenever a routine receives on a channel, that routine blocks until there is something for it to receive.